# Bash how to input data on system prompt

Tags: bash

How do I enter data on system prompts in bash?
Let's say in a bash script, I ssh into a PC.
How do I enter the credentials. 
It may not be even credentials. Something as simple as "do you want to proceed (yes/no):"
How do you enter either yes or no?
I tried echo "yes", but doesn't work. I don't even see "yes" being printed on the screen.

Comment: python is ok also? or only bash

Comment: you can see more here how to work with bash scrip https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Comment: Describe what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to provision remote servers, tools like Chef and Ansible may be better. If you just want to push commands you can specify a script to run when you execute ssh. If you need to respond to ssh's connection prompt, (a) consider using certificates, but (b) the old-school tool to use is called 'expect'. I don't know of a good replacement for that, except other programming languages. Expect itself embeds TCL.

Comment: @rand'Chris take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd just use `echo` or `cat` as in

```
$ touch file
$ echo yes | rm -i file
rm: remove regular file ‘tmp.c’?
```

But note that some programs may behave differently if stdin is non-interactive (i.e. you redirect stdin from `echo`) and some programs (e.g. [ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171841)) read input directly from tty so redirecting stdin will not help. In such cases there are usually program-specific command-line switches to provide input data by other means.

Comment: It looks like touch and ls is not working. Once I ssh and the prompt appears, ls, echo commands are not executed. They are executed after I type the credentials manually. It's as if bash script pauses when the prompt appears.

Comment: "Can you explain how the echo pipe works" - you mean in my example or in general?

Comment: "Once I ssh and the prompt appears, ls, echo commands are not executed" - yes, I mentioned that `ssh` is one of those tools that read their input specially. You need e.g. `sshpass` program to automate it.

Comment: Thanks yugr. Is there a sshpass equivalent for telnet? I was asking how echo pipe works in general case.